# How can I check the time the iPhone application takes to start up?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I'm currently developing a iOS application. I need to compare the time taken to startup on iPhone and/or iPad.  Could someone advise please?

Answer (score 1):

Take note of the current time in `main()` and in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, then calculate the difference. Example:

main.m:

```
// main.m

NSDate *startupDate;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    startupDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    int exitCode = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NULL, @"AppDelegate");
    [startupDate release];
    [pool drain];
    return exitCode;
}

// etc.
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
// AppDelegate.m

extern NSDate *startupDate;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)opts
{
    NSDate *launchFinishedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSTimeInterval launchTimeInSeconds = [launchFinishedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startupDate];
    [launchFinishedDate release];

    // launchTimeInSeconds will contain the launch time in seconds (floating point).
    // create UI setup etc. as usual
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Instruments (included in Xcode) with the Time Profiler to monitor your app's launch.

Comment: on the simulator, but not on an actual device.

Comment: You can do it on both the simulator and the device.